# How to get Twitter search results in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, twitter

I would like to grab a list of the recent appearances of a hashtag, but this seems to be impossible to do in Javascript at the moment.  I have seen a lot of code snippets around that read like:

```
function searchTwitter(query) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?' + searchTerm,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {
            //some code
        }
    });
}
```

However, this does not seem to work anymore.  If I try to use it, I get an error in the console like so:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23twitter. Origin http://myserver.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

The same thing happens if I use $.getJson().  Is there a solution for this?  A workaround?  It seems as though they changed something and then suddenly no one's client-side code works anymore.  I really would like to be able to grab the data using Ajax so I can update my page without having to reload the whole thing.

If I am missing something obvious, please let me know.

Comment: Hmm that's weird/funny/annoying. I can't get it to work in a jsFiddle either - but I'm getting a 403 Forbidden error, not your cross-domain error

Comment: If it helps, here's the fiddle I've been testing with: http://jsfiddle.net/MMNFs/

Comment: Me too had no problems - with API v1. With the new 1.1 version - as i understood it, maybe i'm missing something - no method is accessible without authentication. Looks like you need to setup an app and use its credentials to access the API. See https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq#6974

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this by configurin apache to

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
```

Or for some reasons which i do not understand it worked using `jQuery.getJSON();`

```
function searchTwitter(query) {
    $.getJSON({
        url: 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?' + searchTerm,
        success: function (data) {
            //some code
        }
    });
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: You know, I did try jQuery.getJSON().  I pointed that out in the original post.  Doesn't work.  As far as I know it's just an alias for the .ajax request anyhow.

Comment: @emote_control try to pass callback argument with a blank parameter as ?

Comment: This twitter api call has been deprecated as I received message like "The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview."